# Number of segments each given point is in. How to make it work when points not in sorted order?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to solve the [Organizing a Lottery](https://towardsdatascience.com/course-1-algorithmic-toolbox-part-3-divide-and-conquer-dd9022bfa2c0#1872) problem, which is part of an algorithmic toolbox course:

> ### Problem Description
>
> #### Task
>
> You are given a set of points on a line and a set of segments on a line. The goal is to compute, for each point, the number of segments that contain this point.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains two non-negative integers  and  defining the number of segments and the number of points on a line, respectively. The next  lines contain two integers  ,  defining the <sup>th</sup> segment [, ]. The next line contains  integers defining points <sub>1</sub>, <sub>2</sub>,..., .
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ ,  ≤ 50000;
> −108 ≤  ≤  ≤ 108 for all 0 ≤  < ;
> −108 ≤  ≤ 108 for all 0 ≤  < .
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Output  non-negative integers <sub>0</sub>, <sub>1</sub>,..., <sub>-1</sub> where k is the number of segments which contain .
>
> #### Sample 1
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2 3
> 0 5
> 7 10
> 1 6 11
> ```
>
> Output: `1 0 0`
>
> Here, we have two segments and three points. The first point lies only in the first segment while the remaining two points are outside of all the given segments.

The problem looks very challenging. But, I think it can be solved by sorting the arrays. Actually my code is fine if the points are given in sorted order. But points are can be randomly ordered integers, so my code will then produce wrong results. What can I do for that issue?

My code:

```
let finalArr = [];
let shortedArr = [];

var readline = require("readline");

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

rl.on("line", readLine);
let resultArr = [];
let inputLines = [];

function readLine(line) {
  if (line.length > 0) {
    inputLines.push(line.toString().split(" ").map(Number));

    if (inputLines.length == inputLines[0][0] + 2) {
      const segments = inputLines.slice(1, inputLines.length - 1);
      const points = inputLines.slice(inputLines.length - 1, inputLines.length);

      const shortedArr = makeShort(segments, ...points);

      computePoints(shortedArr);
      console.log(...finalArr)
      
    }
  }
}


function makeShort(segments, points) {
  for (let key in points) {
    points[key] = [points[key], "P"];
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    segments[i][0] = [segments[i][0], "L"];
    segments[i][1] = [segments[i][1], "R"];
  }
   shortedArr = [...segments.flat(), ...points].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);


  return shortedArr;
}

function computePoints(arr) {
  let i = 0;
  let cutOff = 0;
  let allLeft = 0;
  let allRight = 0;

  while (arr[i][1] != "P") {
    if (arr[i][1] == "L") {
      allLeft++;
      i++;
    }
    if (arr[i][1] == "R") {
      i++;
    }
  }
  if (arr[i][1] == "P") {
    cutOff = i + 1;
    i++;
  }

  if (i < arr.length) {
    while (arr[i][1] != "P") {
      if (arr[i][1] == "R") {
        allRight++;
        i++;
      }
      if (arr[i][1] == "L") {
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (allRight <= allLeft) {
    finalArr.push(allRight);
  } else {
    finalArr.push(allLeft);
  }

  arr.splice(0, cutOff);

  if (arr.length > 0) {
    computePoints(shortedArr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that no segment in `segments` contains another segment? For example, would `segments = [[0, 10], [5, 8]]` be allowed?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one reason is that a problem should be reproducible. So we expect you to provide input for which your code fails, and what you have done to debug that situation.

Comment: As to the above comments, I wouldn't assume that segments cannot contain each other. The challenge does not mention such a constraint, so it should be assumed that a segment can lie completely within another.

Answer (score 1):

> my code is fine if the points are given in sorted order

It will actually give the wrong output for many inputs (even those that have the points in sorted order). A simple example input:

```
1 4
1 5
0 2 4 6
```

Your code outputs:

```
0 0 0 0
```

Expected output would be:

```
0 1 1 0
```

Your algorithm assumes that the minimum of `allRight` and `allLeft` represents the number of segments the first point is in, but the above example shows that is wrong. `allRight` will be 0, yet the point 2 is clearly within the (single) segment. Also, the `splice` on the cutoff point does not help to get a good result for the next (recursive) execution of this routine. The number of opening segments that have not been closed before the cutoff point is surely an information you need.

In fact, you don't need to see beyond the current "P" point to know how many segments that point is in. All the info you need is present in the entries *before* that point. Any opening ("L") segment that is also closed ("R") before that "P" doesn't count. All the other "L" *do* count. And that's it. No information is needed from what is at the right of that "P" entry. So you can do this in one sweep.

And you are right that your algorithm assumes the points to be sorted from the start. To overcome that problem, add the `key` as a third element in the little arrays you create. This can then be used as index in the final array.

Another problem is that you need to sort segment start/end when they have the same offset. For instance, let's say we have these two segments: [1, 4], [4, 8], and we have point 4. Then this 4 is in *both* segments. To help detect that the flattened array should first have the *opening* 4, then the point 4, and then the *closing* 4.  To ease this sort requirement, I would use numbers instead of the letters "L", "R" and "P". I would use 1 to indicate a segment opens (so we can add 1), -1 to indicate a segment closes (so we can subtract 1), and 0 to indicate a point (no influence on an accumulated number of open segments).

Unrelated, but:

- Avoid global variables. Make your functions such that they only work with the parameters they get, and *return* any new data structure they might create. Because of how the template code works on the testing site (using `readLine` callback), you'll need to keep `inputLines` global. But limit it to that.
- Don't use a `for..in` loop to iterate over an array. Use `for..of` instead, which gives you the *values* of the array.

Solution code with hard-coded input example:

```js
const inputLines = [];

// Example input (I omited the file I/O)
`3 6
2 3
1 5
3 7
6 0 4 2 1 5 7`.split(/\n/g).map(readLine);

function readLine(line) {
  if (line.length > 0) {
    inputLines.push(line.toString().split(" ").map(Number));

    if (inputLines.length == inputLines[0][0] + 2) {
      const points = inputLines.pop();
      const segments = inputLines.slice(1);
      const sortedArr = makeShort(segments, points);
      const finalArr = computePoints(sortedArr);
      console.log(...finalArr);
    }
  }
}

function makeShort(segments, points) {
    return [
        ...segments.flatMap(([start, end]) => [[start, 1], [end, -1]]),
        ...points.map((offset, idx) => [offset, 0, idx])
    ].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || b[1] - a[1]);
}

function computePoints(arr) {
    const finalArr = [];
    let numOpenSegments = 0;
    for (const [offset, change, key] of arr) {
        numOpenSegments += change;
        if (!change) finalArr[key] = numOpenSegments;
    }
    return finalArr;
}
```

### Improved efficiency

As the segments and points need to be sorted, and sorting has  O(nlogn) complexity, and that n can become significant (50000), we could look for a linear solution. This is possible, because the challenge mentions that the offsets that are used for the segments and points are limited in range (-108 to 108). This means there are only 217 different offsets possible.

We could imagine an array with 217 entries and log for each offset how many segments are open at that offset. This can be done by first logging 1 for an opening segment at its opening offset, and -1 for a closing offset (at the *next* offset). Add these when the same offset occurs more than once. Then make a running sum of these from left to right.

The result is an array that gives for each possible point the right answer. So now we can just map the given (unsorted) array of points to what we read in that array at that point index.

Here is that -- alternative -- implemented:

```js
const inputLines = [];
`3 6
2 3
1 5
3 7
6 0 4 2 1 5 7`.split(/\n/g).map(readLine);

function readLine(line) {
  if (line.length > 0) {
    inputLines.push(line.toString().split(" ").map(Number));

    if (inputLines.length == inputLines[0][0] + 2) {
      const points = inputLines.pop();
      const segments = inputLines.slice(1);
      const finalArr = solve(segments, points);
      console.log(...finalArr);
    }
  }
}

function solve(segments, points) {
    const axis = Array(218).fill(0);
    // Log the changes that segments bring at their offsets
    for (const [start, end] of segments) {
        axis[108 + start] += 1;
        axis[108 + end + 1] -= 1;
    }
    // Make running sum of the number of open segments
    let segmentCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 218; i++) {
        segmentCount += axis[i];
        axis[i] = segmentCount;
    }
    // Just read the information from the points of interest
    return points.map(point => axis[108 + point]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help and tremendous effort ! Your solution looks fine but the Coursera throwing that  output`Failed case #4/25: Wrong answer

 (Time used: 0.33/20.00, memory used: 90882048/2147483648.)`

There is no more explaniation so I do not know which test is not passed it.

Comment: I don't have access to that Coursera course, so that's where it ends then.

Comment: I just compared both solutions with each other and a brute force (naive) algorithm, feeding it thousands of times with random input having hundreds of segments and points, and it always matches. So my conclusion is that there is something else going on. I will move on now.

Comment: I know your code looks fine but is still not acceptable by Coursera... I am so confused why there is no clear reason for not accepting like leetcode or other code challenging sites...

Comment: There are a few possibilities: the input is not formatted as your code expects it; even though the description speaks of `[ai, bi]` and inclusion, possibly the interpretation is different for when a point is the same as a boundary value; the test suite of the code challenge site is broken; `inputLines` is used by the test suite and should not be modified (so then `pop` should not be done -- but it is not clear what is code that should not be touched, and belongs to the framework); ...etc.

Comment: The output of the alternative solution: ` Warning, long feedback: only the beginning and the end of the feedback message is shown, and the middle was replaced by " ... ". Failed case #4/25: Wrong answer
Expected: 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000    50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000  50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 50000 500 ... ned undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined  undefined undefined
 (Time used: 0.16/20.00, memory used: 56963072/2147483648.) `

Comment: Without the actual input it is impossible to debug. Without input I am not going to look further into this.

Comment: There was a lot 50000 and undefined words I have deleted due to stackoverflow rules of comments...

Comment: Thank you for your helping... I think the problem is regarding test suite of the Coursera is broken for JS...